# How can I remove the squares on a surface plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have a matplotlib code to plot a certain 3d function.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L = 10
a = 0.4
type = "COS"
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])

x = np.arange(0, L, 0.05)
y = np.arange(0, 20, 0.05)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
def f(x,t,n):
    return np.cos(n*np.pi*x/L)*np.exp(-a*n*n*np.pi*np.pi*a*t/(L*L))


def s(n):
    if type == "PAR":
        if n > 0:
            return L*L*(4*np.pi*n+4*np.pi*n*((-1)**n))/(2*(np.pi**3)*(n**3))
        else:
            return L*L/12
    elif type == "COS":
        if n > 0:
            return 2*(L*np.sin(L)*((-1)**n))/(L*L-np.pi*np.pi*n*n)
        else:
            return np.sin(L)/L


def g(x,t):
    ans = s(0)
    for n in range(1,200):
        ans += s(n)*f(x,t,n)
    return ans


Z = g(X,Y)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap = plt.cm.inferno)
ax.set_xlabel('x', labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('t', labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel('T', labelpad=20)
plt.show()
```

But, when I go to plot this, I get this:
[image: the graph of the function with squares on the surface]

As you can see, the plotted surface has rectangles on it, and I don't want them. How can I remove them? I tried removing grids and axis but that doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `antialiased=False`:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.inferno, antialiased=False)
```

[image]